# Basic d/dx refresher question

Tags: derivatives

If we have f '(2)=5, does that mean the rate of change 1.999999(infinite number of 9s) to 2 is 5, or to go from 2 to 2.000001 (infinite zeros before 1) is a rate of change of 5?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note : $1.99999...$ actually equals $2$. So does $1.000...1$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...). Moreover, the "rate of change from $x$ to $y$" doesn't mean anything. The derivative of a function at a point is the slope of the curve at that point.

Comment: $f'(2) = 5$ just means that the instantaneous rate of change of $f$ at $x = 2$ is $5$. In other words, $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(2 + h) - f(2)}{h} = 5$.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I remember being taught that the d/dx of a function is what the function's new value would be if x increased by the most marginal amount, which is the same thing as the instantaneous slope you referenced. I just cannot remember if it's the marginal step past the x value or towards the x value.

Comment: Short answer: It's the same value, taking steps "past" $x$ or "towards" $x$. The *derivative* of a function exists at a point if and only if the *left derivative* and *right derivative* both exist and are equal.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Thanks and understood! This was helpful! :)

Comment: There's no such thing as the "most marginal value". $1.999...$ is equal to $2$. We cannot say that $f'(x) = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$ for some extremely tiny value of $h$. All we can say is that, as $h$ gets closer and closer to $0$, $\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$ gets closer and closer to $f'(x)$. It would be worth taking time to understand the concept of a limit more clearly.

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq To be slightly pedantic: $1.000\dots1$ isn't even a number at all – that is not a valid decimal expansion.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such number as $2.000\ldots 1$, and the number $1.999\ldots$ is *exactly* equal $2$.

What $f'(2)=5$ *means* is something else. It means that, by making the interval "around" $2$ (still finite but) small enough, you can make the rate of change  of $f$ in that interval arbitrarily close to $5$. In precise mathematical language, however small $\epsilon\gt 0$ you choose, you can find a small $\delta\gt 0$ (which may depend on $\epsilon$) so that, whenever $2-\delta\lt x\lt 2+\delta$, $x\ne2$ you will have $5-\epsilon\lt\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}\lt 5+\epsilon$.

You may want to be more formal and use symbols such as $\forall$ and $\exists$:

$$(\forall\epsilon\gt 0)(\exists\delta\gt 0)(\forall x)\left(0\lt|x-2|\lt\delta\implies\left|\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}-5\right|\lt\epsilon\right)$$

That is it, and the whole definition involves only arithmetic with real numbers, no "infinitesimally small" quantities of any sort involved.

Note: I am suspicious whether "infinitesimally small" quantities are even useful for *intuition* about calculus. They may be truly misleading. There are ways to define them rigorously (look up "non-standard analysis" on the Web), but then you realise dealing with them is *harder*, rather than easier, than dealing with ordinary real numbers. So - better stay within the realms of the standard real analysis, shall we?

Comment: I agree that infinitesimals are harder to treat rigorously than the standard real analysis methods. But I think they are extremely useful for intuition in applications like volumes of solids of revolution. Physicists use them correctly all the time.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for the response. As outlined in Jair Taylor's response below, H goes towards zero but doesn't equal zero. This is where my infinitesimally small intuition comes in. The limit as defined is not the slope between x=2 and x=2 but x=2 and x+(an infinitesimal small delta). This is the intuition that guided my original post.

Comment: @EthanBolker That is why I said I was "suspicious" rather than being outright against their use. I am not sure. I know translation of what physicists do to a rigorous mathematical concept is a science in itself. The other day we had a question here from a physicist being baffled by a sleight-of-hand replacement of an ordinary power series with a *formal* power series when the former diverged. (Apparently physicists call that "renormalisation", and nobody really knows why it works, when it does, and why it doesn't, when it doesn't...)

Comment: @findingmyway Indeed, you have a right intuition, however the question sounded like you wanted the actual definition of the derivative (or at least to check how far your intuition was from it) - hope those answers will help.

Answer (score 1):

While $1.999\ldots$ is just $2$, and  and $2.00\ldots 1$ is not defined as a real number, the concept of limit is similar to this notion in the following way.

By definition, $$f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$$

Taking $x = 2$ and $h = .00001$, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{f(2.00001) - f(2)}{.00001} \tag{1}
\end{align} is the rate of change of $f$ between $2$ and $2.00001$.  If we take $h = -.00001$, then

$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{f(1.99999) - f(2)}{-.00001} = \frac{f(2) - f(1.99999)}{.00001}\tag{2}$$

is the rate of change of $f$ from $1.99999$ to $2$.

Now what the definition of $f'(2) = 5$ says is that as $h\rightarrow 0$, the difference quotient much approach $5$.  The limit must be a two-sided limit by definition, so we can take $h \rightarrow 0^-$ *or* $h \rightarrow 0^+$ and get the same result, $5$.  This means that as the number of $0$s in the expression (1) gets large enough, the expression will evaluate to as close to $5$ as you want to go; and similarly, as the number of $9$s in (2) gets large enough, the expression will evaluate to as close to $5$ as you want to go.

(If you want to think in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$: letting $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta$ so that $$\big|\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - 5\big| < \epsilon$$ for $|h| < \delta$.  Then if you choose $n$ so that $10^{-n} < \delta$, you are guaranteed that $$\big|\frac{f(2) - f(1.9999\ldots 9)}{.00\ldots 1} - 5 \big| < \epsilon$$ where $1.9999\ldots 9$ means $1$ followed by $n$ 9s and $.00\ldots 1$ means the decimal is followed by $n-1$ $0$s. And the result is is similar for the right-hand limit.)